# Using Common Table Expression (CTE) with Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, common-table-expression

Common Table Expression is a fairly common practice in different RDBMS (PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, SQLite3 etc.) to perform the same calculation multiple times over across multiple query components or for some other purposes

I found old gem [postgres_ext](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/postgres_ext) with such functionality. But it is not maintained. And it is Postgres specific

There are some old questions about it, but they are about specific rails version or specific RDBMS or about `Arel`

- [How do you use the postgresql WITH in activerecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852209/how-do-you-use-the-postgresql-with-in-activerecord)
- [Rails 5.2.2 (active record) WITH statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561592/rails-5-2-2-active-record-with-statement)
- [Postgres Common Table Expression query with Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491908/postgres-common-table-expression-query-with-ruby-on-rails)
- [Arel and CTE to Wrap Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995609/arel-and-cte-to-wrap-query)
- [Multiple CTEs with Arel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091388/multiple-ctes-with-arel)

Is it possible to use `WITH` clause in Rails using AR some common way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37944) Rails 7.1 introduce `with` method that can take few arguments

Let's assume we have `books` table with integer `reviews_count` column. To define and use CTE you can apply [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#with`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-with) such way:

```rb
Book.with(books_with_reviews: Book.where("reviews_count > ?", 0))

# WITH books_with_reviews AS (
#   SELECT * FROM books WHERE (reviews_count > 0)
# )
# SELECT * FROM books
```

It returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, which makes its use very convenient and flexible

For example, after defining a Common Table Expression, it's possible to use name of auxiliary statement with specified `FROM` clause or `JOIN` statement:

```rb
Book
  .with(books_with_reviews: Book.where("reviews_count > ?", 0))
  .from("books_with_reviews AS books")

# WITH books_with_reviews AS (
#  SELECT * FROM books WHERE (reviews_count > 0)
# )
# SELECT * FROM books_with_reviews AS books
```

```rb
Book
  .with(books_with_reviews: Book.where("reviews_count > ?", 0))
  .joins("JOIN books_with_reviews ON books_with_reviews.id = books.id")

# WITH books_with_reviews AS (
#   SELECT * FROM books WHERE (reviews_count > 0)
# )
# SELECT * FROM books JOIN books_with_reviews ON books_with_reviews.id = books.id
```

It's also possible to pass SQL query using `Arel.sql` method:

```rb
Book.with(popular_books: Arel.sql("some SQL literals here"))
```

Important note: double check such arguments to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities, this approach must not be used with unsafe values, especially those containing unsanitized input

To define multiple CTEs just pass few hashes as arguments:

```rb
Book.with(
  books_with_reviews: Book.where("reviews_count > ?", 0),
  books_with_ratings: Book.where("ratings_count > ?", 0)
)

# WITH books_with_reviews AS (
#   SELECT * FROM books WHERE (reviews_count > 0)
# ), books_with_ratings AS (
#   SELECT * FROM books WHERE (ratings_count > 0)
# )
# SELECT * FROM books
```

Since `with` returns relation, you can simply chain it multiple times:

```rb
Book
  .with(books_with_reviews: Book.where("reviews_count > ?", 0))
  .with(books_with_ratings: Book.where("ratings_count > ?", 0))

# WITH books_with_reviews AS (
#   SELECT * FROM books WHERE (reviews_count > 0)
# ), books_with_ratings AS (
#   SELECT * FROM books WHERE (ratings_count > 0)
# )
# SELECT * FROM books
```

Comment: This is nice. Is there a proper way to specify “AS MATERIALIZED” or “NOT MATERIALIZED” as needed?

Comment: @theycallmethesloth currently only Arel supports it. There is "usual" AR [non-merged feature](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/48305)